# Introduction to proofs.

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing

I am not at all familiar with mathematical proof-writing and would like to learn how to create my own proofs. So, I was wondering whether it would be possible for you to recommend me to any book or site that would introduce me to proof-writing.

Additionally, I would like this source to not be of a very high mathematical level and not be about computer science based proofs.

Thank you :)

Comment: I would prefer the information to only be mathematically based and not include programming. Thank you.

Comment: You could use "_Reading, Writing, and Proving: A Closer Look at Mathematics 
A textbook by Pamela Gorkin & Ulrich Daepp_"

Comment: @Nescrio Isn't this college level?

Comment: It is. But at my university we started with this book.. So you only need high school mathematics to understand it. It's a really good introduction to mathematics. If you google the book and add "pdf" behind it you can download the pdf of the book so you could take a look.

Comment: I understand that but I am only in year 9 so I haven't completed high-school yet.

Comment: *Discrete Mathematics Demystified* by Steven Krantz is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original proofs in Mathematics came from the field of Geometry, so a good place to start is there. I recommend:

[Famous Problems in Geometry, and how to solve them](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486242978.html) by Benjamin Bold.